# Tensorflow error InvalidArgumentError: indices[42,244] = -1 is not in [0, 7000)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am new to neural networks and I am trying to train an LSTM network with the following code:

```
# Split the data into training and testing set
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=42)
y_train = list(y_test)
y_test = list(y_test)

embedding_vecor_length = 32
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(7000, embedding_vecor_length, input_length=431))
model.add(LSTM(100))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
print(model.summary())
model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data=(X_test, y_test), epochs=3, batch_size=64)
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
InvalidArgumentError:  indices[42,244] = -1 is not in [0, 7000)
     [[node sequential_290/embedding_77/embedding_lookup (defined at <ipython-input-740-c806f0a9943f>:9) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_12107163]

Errors may have originated from an input operation.
Input Source operations connected to node sequential_290/embedding_77/embedding_lookup:
 sequential_290/embedding_77/embedding_lookup/12105965 (defined at /Users/michalgoldstein/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/contextlib.py:113)

Function call stack:
train_function
```

I tried normalizing the data between 0-1, or as integers, but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding

```
X = np.asarray(X).astype('float32')
y = np.asarray(y).astype('float32')
```

and skipping the normalization part